# Solr returns Unknown aggregation agg_range on facet range query

Tags: solr, faceted-search, solr8

I am using Solr 8.5 and the JSON Facet API. I would like to group by amounts (positive, negative), inside that the categories of my positions, and sum the amounts together. My query is as follows:

```
    POST http://localhost:8983/solr/wallet-positions/select
    Content-Type: application/json

    {
        "

    query": "*:*",
        "limit": 100,
        "facet": {
            "type": "range",
            "field": "amount",
            "ranges": [
                {
                    "from": "0",
                    "inclusive_from": true
                },
                {
                    "to": "0",
                    "inclusive_to": false
                }
            ],
            "facet": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "terms",
                    "field": "category",
                    "missing": true,
                    "facet": {
                        "total_amount": "sum(amount)",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I receive the following exception:

```
"msg": "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Unknown aggregation agg_range in ('range', pos=5)",
```

Any ideas on the problem?

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your facet query (i.e. remove parts of it) to see if the basic range facet works at all, without the dependent facets?

Comment: I have tried the simplified earlier, not with this particular query. In this particular query I have tried to remove the 2 facet (with the category). I receive the same error.